# How to run the gem5 unit tests?

Tags: gem5

Gem5 has several tests in the source tree, and there is some documentation at: http://www.gem5.org/Regression_Tests but those docs are not very clear.

What tests are there and how to run them?

Answer (score 6):

### Unit vs regression tests

gem5 has two kinds of tests:

- regression: run some workload (full system or syscall emulation) on the entire simulator
- unit: test only a tiny part of the simulator, without running the entire simulator binary

We will cover both on this answer.

### Regression tests

#### 2019 regression tests

A new testing framework was added in 2019 and it is documented at: https://gem5.googlesource.com/public/gem5/+/master/TESTING.md

Before sending patches, you basically want to run:

```
cd tests
./main.py run -j `nproc` -t `nproc`
```

This will:

- build gem5 for the actively supported ISAs: X86, ARM, RISCV with `nproc` threads due to `j`
- download binaries required to run tests from gem5.org, e.g. http://www.gem5.org/dist/current/arm/ see also: http://gem5.org/Download It was not currently possible to download out or the source tree, which is bad if you have a bunch of `git worktree`s lying around.
- run the quick tests on `nproc` threads due to `-t`, which should finish in a few minutes

You can achieve the same as the previous command without `cd` by passing the `tests/` directory as an argument:

```
./main.py run -j `nproc` -t `nproc` tests
```

but I wish neither were necessary: https://gem5.atlassian.net/browse/GEM5-397

This is exactly what the automated upstream precommit tests are running as can be seen from [tests/jenkins/presubmit.sh](https://github.com/gem5/gem5/blob/bc26c0dd355f2bbaf2274dd4f549f11efcf84bba/tests/jenkins/presubmit.sh#L50).

Stdout contains clear result output of form:

```
Test: cpu_test_DerivO3CPU_FloatMM-ARM-opt Passed                    
Test: cpu_test_DerivO3CPU_FloatMM-ARM-opt-MatchStdout Passed
Test: realview-simple-atomic-ARM-opt Failed                  
Test: realview-simple-atomic-dual-ARM-opt Failed
```

and details about each test can be found under:

```
tests/.testing-results/
```

e.g.:

```
.testing-results/SuiteUID:tests-gem5-fs-linux-arm-test.py:realview-simple-atomic-ARM-opt/TestUID:tests-gem5-fs-linux-arm-test.py:realview-simple-atomic-ARM-opt:realview-simple-atomic-ARM-opt/
```

although we only see some minimal stdout/stderr output there which don't even show the gem5 stdout. The stderr file does however contain the full command:

```
CalledProcessError: Command '/path/to/gem5/build/ARM/gem5.opt -d /tmp/gem5outJtSLQ9 -re '/path/to/gem5/tests/gem5/fs/linux/arm/run.py /path/to/gem5/master/tests/configs/realview-simple-atomic.py' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

so you can remove `-d` and `-re` and re-run that to see what is happening, which is potentially slow, but I don't see another way.

If a test gets stuck running forever, you can find its raw command with Linux' `ps aux` command since processes are forked for each run.

Request to make it easier to get the raw run commands from stdout directly: https://gem5.atlassian.net/browse/GEM5-627

Request to properly save stdout: https://gem5.atlassian.net/browse/GEM5-608

To further stress test a single ISA, you can run all tests for one ISA with:

```
cd tests
./main.py run -j `nproc` -t `nproc` --isa ARM --length long --length quick
```

Each test is classified as either `long` or `quick`, and using both `--length` runs both.

`long` tests are typically very similar to the default `quick` ones, but using more detailed and therefore slower models, e.g.

- `tests/quick/se/10.mcf/ref/arm/linux/simple-atomic/` is quick with a faster atomic CPU
- `tests/long/se/10.mcf/ref/arm/linux/minor-timing/` is long with a slower Minor CPU

Tested in gem5 69930afa9b63c25baab86ff5fbe632fc02ce5369.

**2019 regression tests run just one test**

List all available tests:

```
./main.py list --length long --length quick
```

This shows both suites and tests, e.g.:

```
SuiteUID:tests/gem5/cpu_tests/test.py:cpu_test_AtomicSimpleCPU_Bubblesort-ARM-opt

TestUID:tests/gem5/cpu_tests/test.py:cpu_test_AtomicSimpleCPU_Bubblesort-ARM-opt:cpu_test_AtomicSimpleCPU_Bubblesort-ARM-opt
TestUID:tests/gem5/cpu_tests/test.py:cpu_test_AtomicSimpleCPU_Bubblesort-ARM-opt:cpu_test_AtomicSimpleCPU_Bubblesort-ARM-opt-MatchStdout
```

And now you can run just one test with `--uid`:

```
./main.py run -j `nproc` -t `nproc` --isa ARM --uid SuiteUID:tests/gem5/cpu_tests/test.py:cpu_test_AtomicSimpleCPU_FloatMM-ARM
```

A bit confusingly, `--uid` must point to a `SuiteUID`, not `TestUID`.

Then, when you run the tests, and any of them fails, and you want to run just the failing one, the test failure gives you a line like:

```
Test: cpu_test_DerivO3CPU_FloatMM-ARM-opt Passed
```

and the only way to run just the test is to `grep` for that string in the output of `./main.py list` since `cpu_test_DerivO3CPU_FloatMM-ARM-opt` is not a full test ID, which is very annoyng.

**2019 regression tests out of tree**

By default, `tests/main.py` places the build at `gem5/build` inside the source tree. Testing an out of tree build is possible with `--build-dir`:

```
./main.py run -j `nproc` -t `nproc` --isa ARM --length quick --build-dir path/to/my/build
```

which places the build in `path/to/my/build/ARM/gem5.opt` instead for example.

If your build is already done, save a few scons seconds with `--skip-build` option as well:

```
./main.py run -j `nproc` -t `nproc` --isa ARM --length quick --build-dir path/to/my/build --skip-build
```

Note however that `--skip-build` also skips the downloading of test binaries. TODO patch that.

**2019 regression tests custom binary download director**

Since https://gem5-review.googlesource.com/c/public/gem5/+/24525 you can use the `--bin-path` option to specify where the test binaries are downloaded, otherwise they just go into the source tree.

This allows you to reuse the large binaries such as disk images across tests in multiple worktrees in a single machine, saving time and space.

#### Pre-2019 regression tests

This way of running tests is deprecated and will be removed.

The tests are run directly with `scons`.

But since the test commands are a bit long, there is even an in-tree utility generate tests commands for you.

For example, to get the command to run X86 and ARM `quick` tests, run:

```
./util/regress -n --builds X86,ARM quick
```

The other options besides `quick` are `long` or `all` to do both `long` and `quick` at the same time.

With `-n` it just prints the test commands, and without it it actually runs them.

This outputs something like:

```
scons \
  --ignore-style \
  --no-lto \
  build/X86/gem5.debug \
  build/ARM/gem5.debug \
  build/X86/gem5.fast \
  build/ARM/gem5.fast \
  build/X86/tests/opt/quick/se \
  build/X86/tests/opt/quick/fs \
  build/ARM/tests/opt/quick/se \
  build/ARM/tests/opt/quick/fs
```

TODO: why does it build gem5.debug and gem5.fast, but then runs an `/opt/` test?

So note how this would both:

- build the gem5 executables, e.g. `build/X86/gem5.debug`
- run the tests, e.g. `build/X86/tests/opt/quick/fs`

Or get the command to run all tests for all archs:

```
./util/regress -n all
```

Then, if you just want to run one of those types of tests, e.g. the `quick` X86 ones you can copy paste the `scons` just for that tests:

```
scons --ignore-style build/X86/tests/opt/quick/se
```

Running the tests with an out of tree build works as usual by magically parsing the target path: [How to build gem5 out of tree?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54343515/how-to-build-gem5-out-of-tree/54343516#54343516)

```
scons --ignore-style /any/path/that/you/want/build/X86/tests/opt/quick/se
```

or you can pass the `--build-dir` option to `util/regress`:

```
./util/regress --build-dir /any/path/that/you/want all
```

The tests that boot Linux on the other hand require a Linux image with a specific name in the `M5_PATH`, which is also annoying.

This would however be very slow, not something that you can run after each commit: you are more likely to want to run just the quick tests for your ISA of interest.

#### Pre-2019 regression tests: Run just one test

If you just append the path under `tests` in the source tree to the test commands, it runs all the tests under a given directory.

For example, we had:

```
scons --ignore-style build/X86/tests/opt/quick/se
```

and we notice that the following path exists under `tests` in the source tree:

```
quick/se/00.hello/ref/x86/linux/simple-atomic/
```

so we massage the path by removing `ref` to get the final command:

```
scons build/X86/tests/opt/quick/se/00.hello/x86/linux/simple-atomic
```

#### Pre-2019 regression tests: Find out the exact gem5 CLI of the command run

When you run the tests, they output to stdout the m5out path.

Inside the m5out path, there is a simout with the emulator stdout, which contains the full gem5 command line used.

For example:

```
scons --ignore-style build/X86/tests/opt/quick/se
```

outputs:

```
Running test in /any/path/that/you/want/build/ARM/tests/opt/quick/se/00.hello/arm/linux/simple-atomic.
```

and the file:

```
/any/path/that/you/want/build/ARM/tests/opt/quick/se/00.hello/arm/linux/simple-atomic
```

contains:

```
command line: /path/to/mybuild/build/ARM/gem5.opt \
  -d /path/to/mybuild/build/ARM/tests/opt/quick/fs/10.linux-boot/arm/linux/realview-simple-atomic \
  --stats-file 'text://stats.txt?desc=False' \
  -re /path/to/mysource/tests/testing/../run.py \
  quick/fs/10.linux-boot/arm/linux/realview-simple-atomic
```

#### Pre-2019 regression tests: Re-run just one test

If you just run a test twice, e.g. with:

```
scons build/ARM/tests/opt/quick/fs/10.linux-boot/arm/linux/realview-simple-atomic
scons build/ARM/tests/opt/quick/fs/10.linux-boot/arm/linux/realview-simple-atomic
```

the second run will not really re-run the test, but rather just compare the stats from the previous run.

To actually re-run the test, you must first clear the stats generated from the previous run before re-running:

```
rm -rf build/ARM/tests/opt/quick/fs/10.linux-boot/arm/linux/realview-simple-atomic
```

#### Pre-2019 regression tests: Get test results

Even this is messy... `scons` does not return `0` success and `1` for failure, so you have to parse the logs. One easy way it to see:

```
scons --ignore-style build/X86/tests/opt/quick/se |& grep -E '^\*\*\*\*\* '
```

which contains three types of results: `PASSSED`, `CHANGED` or `FAILED`

`CHANGED` is mostly for stat comparisons that had a great difference, but those are generally very hard to maintain and permanently broken, so you should focus on `FAILED`

Note that most tests currently rely on [SPEC2000](https://www.spec.org/) and fail unless you have access to this non-free benchmark...

### Unit tests

The unit tests, which compile to separate executables from `gem5`, and just test a tiny bit of the code.

There are currently two types of tests:

- `UnitTest`: old and deprecated, should be converted to `GTest`
- `GTest`: new and good. Uses [Google Test](https://github.com/abseil/googletest).

  Placed next to the class that they test, e.g.:

  ```
  src/base/cprintf.cc
  src/base/cprintf.hh
  src/base/cprintftest.cc
  ```

Compile and run all the `GTest` unit tests:

```
scons build/ARM/unittests.opt
```

Sample output excerpt:

```
build/ARM/base/cprintftest.opt --gtest_output=xml:build/ARM/unittests.opt/base/cprintftest.xml
Running main() from gtest_main.cc
[==========] Running 4 tests from 1 test case.
[----------] Global test environment set-up.
[----------] 4 tests from CPrintf
[ RUN      ] CPrintf.Misc
[       OK ] CPrintf.Misc (0 ms)
[ RUN      ] CPrintf.FloatingPoint
[       OK ] CPrintf.FloatingPoint (0 ms)
[ RUN      ] CPrintf.Types
[       OK ] CPrintf.Types (0 ms)
[ RUN      ] CPrintf.SpecialFormatting
[       OK ] CPrintf.SpecialFormatting (0 ms)
[----------] 4 tests from CPrintf (0 ms total)

[----------] Global test environment tear-down
[==========] 4 tests from 1 test case ran. (0 ms total)
[  PASSED  ] 4 tests.
```

Compile and run just one test file:

```
scons build/ARM/base/cprintf.test.opt
./build/ARM/base/cprintf.test.opt
```

List available test functions from a test file, and run just one of them:

```
./build/ARM/base/cprintftest.opt --gtest_list_tests
./build/ARM/base/cprintftest.opt SpecialFormatting
```

Tested on gem5 200281b08ca21f0d2678e23063f088960d3c0819, August 2018.

#### Unit tests with SimObjects

As of 2019, the unit tests are quite limited, because devs haven't yet found a proper way to test SimObjects in isolation, which make up the bulk of the simulator, and are tightly bound to the rest of the simulator. This unmerged patch attempted to address that: https://gem5-review.googlesource.com/c/public/gem5/+/15315

It might be possible to work around it with Google Mock, which is already present in-tree, but it is not clear if anyone has the patience to mock out enough of SimObject to actually make such tests.

I believe the only practical solution is to embed all tests into gem5.opt, and then have a `--test <testname>` option that runs tests instead of running simulating. This way we get a single binary without duplicating binary sizes, but can still access everything.

Related issue: https://gem5.atlassian.net/browse/GEM5-433

### Continuous integration

#### 20.1 Nightlies enabled

As mentioned at: https://www.gem5.org/project/2020/10/01/gem5-20-1.html a Jenkins that runs the long regressions was added at: https://jenkins.gem5.org/job/Nightly/

#### 2019 CI

Around 2019-04  a precommit CI that runs after every pull request after the maintainer gives +1.

It uses a magic semi-internal Google provided Jenkins setup called Kokoro which provides low visibility on configuration.

See this for example: https://gem5-review.googlesource.com/c/public/gem5/+/18108 That server does not currently run nightlies. The entry point is `tests/jenkins/presubmit.sh`.

Nightlies were just disabled to start with.

#### What is the environment of the 2019 CI?

In-tree Docker images are used: https://askubuntu.com/questions/350475/how-can-i-install-gem5/1275773#1275773

#### Pre-2019 CI update

here was a server running somewhere that runs the quick tests for all archs nightly and posts them on the dev mailing list, adding to the endless noise of that enjoyable list :-)

Here is a sample run: https://www.mail-archive.com/gem5-dev@gem5.org/msg26855.html

As of 2019Q1, gem5 devs are trying to setup an automated magic Google Jenkins to run precommit tests, a link to a prototype can be found at: https://gem5-review.googlesource.com/c/public/gem5/+/17456/1#message-e9dceb1d3196b49f9094a01c54b06335cea4ff88 This new setup uses the new testing system in `tests/main.py`.

#### Pre-2019 CI: Why so many tests are `CHANGED` all the time?

As of August 2018, many tests have been `CHANGED` for a long time.

This is because stats can vary due to a very wide number of complex
factors. Some of those may be more accurate, others no one knows,
others just bugs.

Changes happen so often that devs haven't found the time to properly
understand and justify them.

If you really care about why they changed, the best advice I have is to bisect them.

But generally your best bet is to just re-run your old experiments on the newer gem5 version, and compare everything there.

gem5 is not a cycle accurate system simulator, so absolute values or
small variations are not meaningful in general.

This also teaches us that results obtained with small margins are
generally not meaningful for publication since the noise is too great.

What that error margin is, I don't know.