# How to build gem5 out of tree?

Tags: gem5

The normal build command:

```
scons build/ARM/gem5.opt
```

places the build inside the source tree at:

```
build/
```

How to place it in a custom location?

I could not find any relevant scons options.

Answer (score 0):

I [asked on the mailing list](https://www.mail-archive.com/gem5-users@gem5.org/msg15427.html) and the devs showed me that the following works:

```
scons /any/path/that/you/want/build/ARM/gem5.opt
```

gem5's build system just parses the path magically, and extracts the arch and `opt` from it.

The `build/` part is mandatory.

Tested on gem5 8e11ea0e5862f2b088b4b21c32933b623b84efcc