# Having hdf5.cc causes errors in Gem5 build?

Tags: gem5

I moved my Gem5 simulations from my system to a server. My system does not have HDF5 libraries, but the server has, and I am met with this error:

> ```
> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/config/libpython2.7.a(posixmodule.o): In function `posix_tmpnam':
> /space/src/Python-2.7/./Modules/posixmodule.c:7275: warning: the use of `tmpnam_r' is dangerous, better use `mkstemp'
> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/config/libpython2.7.a(posixmodule.o): In function `posix_tempnam':
> /space/src/Python-2.7/./Modules/posixmodule.c:7230: warning: the use of `tempnam' is dangerous, better use `mkstemp'
> build/X86/base/lib.o.partial: In function `Stats::Hdf5::addMetaData(H5::DataSet&, char const*, double)':
> /net/nasstore/students/GRAD/ECE/febinps/home/Paper3/gem5/build/X86/base/stats/hdf5.cc:312: undefined reference to `H5::H5Object::createAttribute(char const*, H5::DataType const&, H5::DataSpace const&, H5::PropList const&) const'
> build/X86/base/lib.o.partial: In function `Stats::Hdf5::addMetaData(H5::DataSet&, char const*, std::vector<char const*, std::allocator<char const*> > const&)':
> /net/nasstore/students/GRAD/ECE/febinps/home/Paper3/gem5/build/X86/base/stats/hdf5.cc:280: undefined reference to `H5::H5Object::createAttribute(char const*, H5::DataType const&, H5::DataSpace const&, H5::PropList const&) const'
> build/X86/base/lib.o.partial: In function `Stats::Hdf5::addMetaData(H5::DataSet&, char const*, std::string const&)':
> /net/nasstore/students/GRAD/ECE/febinps/home/Paper3/gem5/build/X86/base/stats/hdf5.cc:302: undefined reference to `H5::H5Object::createAttribute(char const*, H5::DataType const&, H5::DataSpace const&, H5::PropList const&) const'
> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
> scons: *** [build/X86/gem5.opt] Error 1
> scons: building terminated because of errors.
> ```

How can I fix this? Is there an yway I can avoid the build from using HDF5? I cannot do much at the server as I do not have admin access.

Comment: What's your GCC version, OS version, and gem5 version?

Comment: I've also tried it, and on Ubuntu 19.10 I'm hit a problem and reported it: https://gem5.atlassian.net/browse/GEM5-365

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the root cause of this issue, some one who is working on Gem5 could possibly answer that.

But as a workaround, since I have no admin access to the server ,and even then removing a library just for the sake of one build doesn't feel right, I edited the SConstruct file in gem5/, where the environment variables are gathered and passed:

```
have_hdf5 = 0 #check_hdf5() #line number 951 in the SConstruct file
```

This seems to work for the build.

Comment: `scons USE_HDF5=0` will also likely work without patching.

Answer (score 1):

After the resolution of: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1187343/installation-of-gem5-on-ubuntu-19-10-on-my-laptop-i5-cpu-m520-64bit in gem5 b383997d4a9c642dd4356bfc4554ac7ae183ae62 (March 2020) the Ubuntu 19.10 (GCC 9) build is working for me:

```
scons -j `nproc` build/ARM/gem5.opt
```

If you find any further build bugs, do open an issue on the Jira issue tracker.

After https://gem5-review.googlesource.com/c/public/gem5/+/34777 gem5 should be building every time with HDF5 on the [upstream testing system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52279971/how-to-run-the-gem5-unit-tests) see also https://askubuntu.com/questions/350475/how-can-i-install-gem5/1275773#1275773 so I don't think it will break again easily.

Answer (score 0):

In case you run on older system like Debian 10 or Ubuntu 16.04, the errors are due to the fact that the `hdf5` library path is not in default system library path.  I solved it by manually (brutally) linking gem5 ...

The link flags added are:
`-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/hdf5/serial/ -lhdf5_cpp -lhdf5`

```sh
g++ -o /gem5/default/build/X86/gem5.opt \
    -Wl,--as-needed -fuse-ld=gold -L/usr/lib/python2.7/config-x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib \
    -Xlinker -export-dynamic \
    -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -z origin -O3 \
    /gem5/default/build/X86/sim/main.o \
    /gem5/default/build/X86/dev/net/lib.o.partial \
    /gem5/default/build/X86/base/lib.o.partial \
    /gem5/default/build/X86/dev/i2c/lib.o.partial \
    /gem5/default/build/X86/cpu/testers/traffic_gen/lib.o.partial \
    /gem5/default/build/X86/mem/cache/tags/indexing_policies/lib.o.partial \
    /gem5/default/build/X86/mem/ruby/slicc_interface/lib.o.partial \
    /gem5/default/build/X86/mem/probes/lib.o.partial \
    /gem5/default/build/X86/mem/ruby/network/simple/lib.o.partial \
    /gem5/default/build/X86/dev/x86/lib.o.partial \
    /gem5/default/build/X86/mem/ruby/network/fault_model/lib.o.partial \
    /gem5/default/build/X86/systemc/utils/lib.o.partial \
    /gem5/default/build/X86/systemc/dt/int/lib.o.partial \
    /gem5/default/build/X86/cpu/kvm/lib.o.partial \
    /gem5/default/build/X86/cpu/simple/probes/lib.o.partial \
    /gem5/default/build/X86/base/filters/lib.o.partial \
    /gem5/default/build/X86/dev/serial/lib.o.partial \
    /gem5/default/build/X86/sim/power/lib.o.partial \
    /gem5/default/build/X86/mem/cache/tags/lib.o.partial \
    /gem5/default/build/X86/arch/x86/bios/lib.o.partial \
    /gem5/default/build/X86/systemc/dt/fx/lib.o.partial \
    /gem5/default/build/X86/mem/ruby/common/lib.o.partial \
    /gem5/default/build/X86/mem/ruby/network/garnet2.0/lib.o.partial \
    /gem5/default/build/X86/mem/ruby/structures/lib.o.partial \
    /gem5/default/build/X86/cpu/testers/garnet_synthetic_traffic/lib.o.partial \
    /gem5/default/build/X86/mem/cache/prefetch/lib.o.partial \
    /gem5/default/build/X86/cpu/trace/lib.o.partial \
    /gem5/default/build/X86/sim/probe/lib.o.partial \
    /gem5/default/build/X86/sim/lib.o.partial \
    /gem5/default/build/X86/mem/ruby/protocol/lib.o.partial \
    /gem5/default/build/X86/systemc/tlm_core/2/quantum/lib.o.partial \
    /gem5/default/build/X86/cpu/simple/lib.o.partial \
    /gem5/default/build/X86/base/vnc/lib.o.partial \
    /gem5/default/build/X86/mem/ruby/system/lib.o.partial \
    /gem5/default/build/X86/mem/cache/lib.o.partial \
    /gem5/default/build/X86/arch/x86/lib.o.partial \
    /gem5/default/build/X86/dev/storage/lib.o.partial \
    /gem5/default/build/X86/mem/protocol/lib.o.partial \
    /gem5/default/build/X86/systemc/core/lib.o.partial \
    /gem5/default/build/X86/systemc/tlm_core/2/generic_payload/lib.o.partial \
    /gem5/default/build/X86/cpu/testers/directedtest/lib.o.partial \
    /gem5/default/build/X86/mem/ruby/profiler/lib.o.partial \
    /gem5/default/build/X86/arch/x86/regs/lib.o.partial \
    /gem5/default/build/X86/dev/pci/lib.o.partial \
    /gem5/default/build/X86/cpu/o3/probe/lib.o.partial \
    /gem5/default/build/X86/mem/cache/compressors/lib.o.partial \
    /gem5/default/build/X86/cpu/lib.o.partial \
    /gem5/default/build/X86/learning_gem5/part2/lib.o.partial \
    /gem5/default/build/X86/mem/cache/replacement_policies/lib.o.partial \
    /gem5/default/build/X86/dev/virtio/lib.o.partial \
    /gem5/default/build/X86/proto/lib.o.partial \
    /gem5/default/build/X86/cpu/testers/rubytest/lib.o.partial \
    /gem5/default/build/X86/mem/qos/lib.o.partial \
    /gem5/default/build/X86/cpu/pred/lib.o.partial \
    /gem5/default/build/X86/python/lib.o.partial \
    /gem5/default/build/X86/arch/generic/lib.o.partial \
    /gem5/default/build/X86/systemc/tlm_bridge/lib.o.partial \
    /gem5/default/build/X86/dev/lib.o.partial \
    /gem5/default/build/X86/kern/lib.o.partial \
    /gem5/default/build/X86/mem/lib.o.partial \
    /gem5/default/build/X86/cpu/testers/memtest/lib.o.partial \
    /gem5/default/build/X86/systemc/dt/misc/lib.o.partial \
    /gem5/default/build/X86/systemc/tlm_utils/lib.o.partial \
    /gem5/default/build/X86/cpu/o3/lib.o.partial \
    /gem5/default/build/X86/mem/ruby/network/lib.o.partial \
    /gem5/default/build/X86/systemc/dt/bit/lib.o.partial \
    /gem5/default/build/X86/dev/ps2/lib.o.partial \
    /gem5/default/build/X86/unittest/lib.o.partial \
    /gem5/default/build/X86/systemc/channel/lib.o.partial \
    /gem5/default/build/X86/systemc/dt/lib.o.partial \
    /gem5/default/build/X86/base/date.o \
    -L/gem5/default/build/libelf -L/gem5/default/build/fputils -L/gem5/default/build/libfdt -L/gem5/default/build/drampower -L/gem5/default/build/iostream3 -L/gem5/default/build/nomali -L/gem5/default/build/googletest -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/hdf5/serial/ \
    -lpython2.7 -lpthread -ldl -lutil -lm -lz -lprotobuf -lrt -ltcmalloc -lnomali -liostream3 \
    -ldrampower -lfdt -lfputils -lelf -lhdf5_cpp -lhdf5
```